# Regex to skip a date in the input

Tags: regex

I have dates like this i want to match all the dates except
 `03/01/2015, 03/01/2016`

Have no access to dates function to use here system is like that.

**input:**

```
03/01/2015, 03/21/2015, 03/22/2016, 03/01/2015
```

I am trying like but unable to find

```
03\/[^0]?1\/(2015|2016)
```

i am thinking we have to use some negative techniques here.

https://regex101.com/r/iZ9oA2/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you should use a negative look-ahead with a generic pattern:

```
\b(?!03\/01\/(?:1\d|201\d)\b)\d{2}\/\d{2}\/(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yT2vS3/6)

This regex should also exclude the dates with 2-digit years that belong to `10`-ies.

Or, if you just want to not match a specific *day* in March 2015/2016:

```
\b03\/(?!01)\d{2}\/201[56]\b
```

Or (allowing 2-digit years)

```
\b03\/(?!01)\d{2}\/(?:20)?1[56]\b
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA6sP1/3)

Comment: hi stribizhev could you pls club the year as 2 digits if possible

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti: No, [it won't match any `201x` year dates](https://regex101.com/r/yT2vS3/3) because of `\d`.

Comment: satisfied with the answer but can't use it is a product it might go long years

Comment: Just a sec,  I am thinking about how to adjust the lookahead for 2-digit years.

Comment: is there any chance we can use like this /^(01)  ??

Comment: i am trying like 03\/^(01)\/(2015|2016) if we unmatch the day then it will work perfectly

Comment: i think i got one 03\/([^0]?\d|[^1])\/(2015|2016) does this works?

Comment: `[^1]` will match `§`. Or a newline, or anything but a `1`. Same with `[^0]`. You need to read the [*lookaround section on regular-expressions.info*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: how about this 03\/(([0]?[^1])?\/\d+|[^0]\d\/\d+) ??

Comment: If you plan to match a single digit that is not `1`, you must use `[02-9]`. It is not the same as `[^1]`. Your regex above will also match [`03/%1/2015`](https://regex101.com/r/jA6sP1/4)

Comment: finally i got what i wanted ^(?!08\/01\/2016|08\/15\/2016|09\/01\/2016).*$

Comment: And this is exactly the same technique I showed with my first regex. :) Glad you mastered it.

Comment: Everything comes with practice.